# What does "got him turned" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [The International (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_International_(2009_film)), after he interrogates Wexler for working in an illegal company IBBC, interpol detective Salinger meets Eleanor Whitman outside:

> Whitman: You've already **got him turned**. Now go back in there and get
> him to come in on his own. We can use everything. We'll blow this
> whole thing wide open.

What does "got him turned" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning in this sentence is probably

> [27. to cause (an enemy agent) to become a double agent working for one's own side](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn)

If Wexler is working for IBBC, but is also providing information to Salinger about IBBC, then one natural interpretation is that Whitman is saying "You have already succeeded in getting him to work for us instead of his employers."